# How do I install bower packages using Cake (http://cakebuild.net)

Tags: c#, powershell, build, bower, cakebuild

I am working on migrating a Powershell build script to Cake script and previously I would have run the following on a collection of directories where the bower.json files were found:

```
foreach ($directory in (Get-CommonPath $bowerDirs)) {
    Push-Location $directory
    &bower install
    Pop-Location
}
```

But since there doesn't seem to be a cake alias for bower I'm struggling to work out how I should do this (`&bower install`) using Cake.

UPDATE
Based on @garyewanpark's answer I tried the following

```
Task("BowerInstall")
  .Does(() => {
    var bowerRoots = GetBowerRoots();
    foreach (var bowerRoot in bowerRoots.Select(x => x.FullPath))
    {
      try 
      {
        var exitCodeWithArgument = StartProcess("bower", new ProcessSettings {
          Arguments = "install",
          WorkingDirectory = bowerRoot
        });
        Information("Exit code: {0}", exitCodeWithArgument);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Information($"Failed on {bowerRoot}, {ex.Message}");
      }
    }
  });
```

But this gave the following error message for each path attempted

> Failed on C:/Projects/dev/WebUI, The system cannot find
>   the file specified

If running bower install in the directory using a command prompt it runs successfully

The directory structure this is running in is described below.
There are multiple solutions within a single git branch. Each solution can contain multiple projects and some have a bower.json file. The GetBowerRoots() method returns a DirectoryPathCollection of directories that contain a bower.json file.

```
c:\
  - Projects
    - Branch
      - build.ps1
      - build.cake
      - Sol1
        - Proj1
          - Misc proj files
          - bower.json
      - Sol2
        - Proj2
          - Misc proj files
          - bower.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Cake.Bower Addin has now been created, and is available for download from here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Bower/

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there currently is not an addin for Bower within Cake.  There are though a few things that you can do.

The first, would be to create an addin for this task.  There is a blog series by Jamie Philips on how you can start doing this, and this can be found in our resources section [here](https://www.cakebuild.net/docs/resources/blogs).

The second option would be to make use of the Cake.Npm addin.  Within my package.json file, I typically make the `install` command do a `bower install` while the `init` command does the `npm install`.  This has the effect of doing both an npm and bower install while emitting only one command in the Cake.Npm addin.

The final one, which I think would make sense for you right now would be to use one of the Process Aliases, which are documented [here](https://www.cakebuild.net/dsl/process/).  For example, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var exitCodeWithArgument = StartProcess("bower", new ProcessSettings { 
    Arguments = "install",
    WorkingDirectory = <path to folder> 
});

// This should output 0 as valid arguments supplied
Information("Exit code: {0}", exitCodeWithArgument);
```

**NOTE:**  In order to get this to work, I had to fully declare the path to where bower lives, which I didn't expect to have to do.  To find out where this is on your machine, run the command:

```
&where.exe bower
```

From a PowerShell prompt, or simply:

```
where bower
```

From a command window.  This will output all of the locations that bower resides.  So the final code looks like the following, which I have tested and it works:

```
foreach (var bowerRoot in bowerRoots.Select(x => x.FullPath))
{
  try
  {
    var exitCodeWithArgument = StartProcess("C:/Users/gary.park/AppData/Roaming/npm/bower.cmd", new ProcessSettings {
        Arguments = "install",
        WorkingDirectory = bowerRoot
    });
    Information("Exit code: {0}", exitCodeWithArgument);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Information(string.Format("Failed on {0}, {1}", bowerRoot,   ex.Message));
  }
}
```

Comment: Push/Pop location would be replaced by WorkingDirectory on process settings https://www.cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/ProcessSettings/

Comment: Thanks @Gary-Ewan-Park. Incidentally it was you that got me onto cake with your talk at DDD Reading about a year ago. Finally convinced the team to switch so thanks for that :)
I've tried option number three and although bower works from the command line as it is installed globally I'm getting a "The system cannot find the file specified" error when running from the cake script. Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Glad to hear that you are liking it! I suspect that the issue is the Working Directory that @devlead mentioned above.  Have you set that in the ProcessSettings class?  Perhaps you could share a snippet of your Cake Script, with a reproducible example?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I've tried setting that yeh. It works fine with other commands such as ping, but not bower. I've updated the question and put a copy of the task I've been running in there. Thanks again for your help. Oh, btw. I'm running with the -experimental flag hence the string interpolation

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the folder structure that you are using?  Or perhaps, create a folder structure the mimics what you are using?  Just want to make sure that we are on the same page?

Comment: I've added a skeleton structure that I think adequately describes it above.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working solution.  So, even though `bower` is on my path, it isn't found when running through `StartProcess` and that is the error that you are seeing.  Fully declaring the path to the bower command works.  Perhaps @devlead can offer some suggestions as to why this would be necessary?

Comment: Try on windows launching with "cmd" as command and "/c bower install" if that works it's likely because .cmd isn't found.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark devead Many thanks to you both. This is definitely useful knowledge for working with cake
I had some spare time today so built a working AddIn https://github.com/wozzo/Cake.Bower
I'll try and do more with it over the next few weeks.

Comment: Doh! I have just been working on the same over here: https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Bower been at it for about an hour, and have the guts of it working, but looks like your's is in a better state.  Would you be interested in transferring your code over to this cake-contrib repository, so that other people can work on it as well?  Thanks for creating this addin by the way!